# Is any damage to an electrical cable acceptable?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We had electricians over today and they struggled to pull the cable for a new subpanel. They are planing to finish tomorrow. Now that they left, I checked the cable and the plastic protection is damaged in some places. The picture is from the worst part I could see and close to the end so they might be able to cut it off. However, I see other much smaller places as well.

I am not sure what cable it is but it seems to have a second layer of protection around all wires and then the individual plastic around each wire. The three layers in total with small holes in the first. Is any damage to the outer cable protection acceptable? Should we ask them to replace the entire cable? Or are small holes in the outer protection acceptable considering that there are two more layers?

The printing on the cable says something like SER 1/0 AL.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How about  picture of the whole section of cable.

Comment: How close to the end of the cable is this?

Comment: Wow, they messed that up and will have to re-do it.  It will never pass inspection.  Fortunately for them, 1/0Al is cheap.

Comment: I just added additional pictures that show a smaller hole in the outer shell and also a picture of how the cable looks like with the three layers of protection for each wire in the cable. The part with the bigger hole is close to the end and can be cut off. The smaller hole can not.

Comment: I love it , the outer jacket is designed to take the damage and if the inner jacket is not damaged it is fine. Where is the the location of the damage it’s hard to tell this close up but if concerned toss a few wraps of tape on it

Comment: @EdBeal, the in er jacket is not damaged in the smaller spot. So is this acceptable damage or not? What does the inspector and code say?

Comment: @harper-reinstateukraine, even with just the smaller hole on the outer jacket? Does any damage to the jacket require replacement according to code?

Comment: Such interpretive decisions are made by the AHJ (permit issuer/inspector).  I would show these photos to them.  What they say is the last word.